# How does Intellij code inspection decide on selectors from .css files?

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity, code-inspection

I have a `css` file in which there's a selector for class App-logo

```
.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 75px;
}
```

The file is in `resources/public` directory.

In the `resources` directory, there's a file called `testform.vtl` (a velocity file), in which the following lines appear:

```
      <div class="App-header" >
         <img src="favicon.png"  class="App-logo pull-left" alt="logo"  />
         <h2>Data Insight - Known Issues Console </h2>
      </div>
```

When I run code inspection in Intellij, it gives me the warning `Selector app-logo is never used`.  Why is this? Is there a configuration that I can use in Intellij to cause it to look at these vtl files (if this is actually the problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE only looks for CSS selector usages in stylesheets and HTML files/fragments; it won't inspect plain text files and files of unknown type. I've just checked - CSS usages are correctly found in Velocity templates:

[image]

Make sure to add `*.vtl` pattern to **Velocity Template** file type in **Settings | Editor | File Types**